# shutdown all the task in ThreadPool java 5

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using thread executor of Java 5 , and running several tasks which implements the interface `callable`.

The issue that my task running in loop and once I want to exit from my application I am calling the `shutdownNow()` method ,which is not good because it stop all task that finished work

And I have 2 task which is not finished so 2 thread still running even after I close my application.

Is there an API that can insure that all my threads stopped immediately or I should implements some interface or add stop method to my each thread.

Because the interface `Callable` has just one method call. And there is not stop method.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [`ExecutorService#shutdownNow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) javadoc:

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
>
> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

So, you need to regularly check [`Thread#isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) inside the `call()` yourself. You can do that in for example some `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to order all thread to stop then you should add a flag test inside the thread code:

```
while(!stop) {
    // do work
}
```

And set the flag to true when you want to exit the program. Don't forget to make it `volatile`.

If you only want to wait for all of them to finish before exiting the program, use:

```
executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```